# how to create the collection in mongodb without any document using mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried to copy collections from first db to second db, collections those having documents are copied from first db to second db, but collections with no documents are not getting copied. when I tried to create new collection with empty document, collection gets created with one document containing id field.But my requirement is to create collection without any document in mongodb using mongoose.How to create empty collection in MongoDb using mongoose library and node.js. here goes the code

```
var data = db.model('name', 'mymodel',"collectionName"),
   newCollection = new data({});
   newCollection .save(function (err) {});
```

Comment: Could you please show some code so we can see what you have already tried?

Comment: var data = db.model('name', 'mymodel',"collectionName"),
   newCollection = new data({});
   newCollection .save(function (err) {});  when new data({}) is used new collection created with one document field containing _id. how to create empty collection?

Comment: Can you edit it into your question?

Comment: Just do a db.createCollection('name') - it will create an empty collection without an id.

Comment: need to create collection using mongoose in nodejs

Comment: @Nandhini Were you able to find a solution for this? If so can you please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native MongoDb driver to create an empty collection.

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName', function(err, db) {
    db.createCollection(collectionName, function(err, collection) {
          db.close();
    })
})
```

Now you can take this a step further and check if the collection exists. If its does skip creation or else create one.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName', function(err, db) {

    db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {
        var collectionExists = false;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err,null,1));
        if(!err && collections && collections.length>0){
            _.each(collections,function (co) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(co.name,null,1));
                if(co.name == collectionName){
                    collectionExists = true;
                }
            })
        }

        if(!collectionExists){
            db.createCollection(collectionName, function(err, collection) {

            })
        }
        db.close();
    });
})
```

References:

1. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections
2. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#createCollection